# Animating Object not moving towards player - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have an enemy and an animation component is attached to it, and in this component I have attached 'animation clip', which is walking animation, In this walking animation, the model (enemy) is not moving (translating). So I decided to create a script so that the enemy could walk towards the player.

I created a script.

```
void Update () {

        transform.LookAt(player);
        transform.position -= Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime; 
    }
```

Now the enemy is moving towards the player if player is in 'z' direction only,

but when I change the position of the player, the enemy is not moving towards the player. Can you help me to move the enemy towards the player ?

Here is the video URL for easy understanding - http://tinypic.com/r/307ulu0/9

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing
 `transform.position -= Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;` to

`transform.position = Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime;`

If that doesn't work try using the MoveTowards method.

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, speed*Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Great, It gave me idea, Thanks , little change to your code - as   public Transform target;
    public float speed;
    void Update() {
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
    }